# how to table values in php

Tags: php, php-5.2

I have TWO table

1. task_emp_designation
2. task_employee

---

*task emp_designation table like this *

> - id -> 1 2 3 4
> - designation -> webdeveloper, designe, tester, programmer

And task_employee tabel one field nane is there, called emp_designation,in that table i stored like 1 or 4 or 3 ...

For my question is while selecting the emp_designation values,it will return like 1 or 4 or 3,
i want to show 1 means developer,2 means designer ,3 means tester,like that i want show,i don't know how to do this

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please specify which DBMS you are using and attempted codes. Basically you only need to fetch the data as associative array, and print the value of `$designation_name_array[$id]`.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT task_employee.id, task_emp_designation.designation 
FROM task_employee 
INNER JOIN task_emp_designation
ON task_employee.emp_designation = task_emp_designation.id;
```

That would do what you want if I understood you correctly